Spectral efficiency of OFDM
For OFDM we know that:

$R_b^{OFDM} = N \cdot R_s \cdot \log_2(M)$

Where N is the number of subcarriers, $R_s = 1/T_s $ is the subcarrier bit rate and $\log_2(M) = \ell$ is the number of bits per carrier symbol.

$B_T = \frac{N+1}{T} =  \frac{N+1}{N.T_s}$
Where $T$ is the (total) OFDM symbol length.

Which would then yield
$$ \eta^{OFDM} = \frac{R_b^{OFDM} }{B_T} = \frac{N \cdot R_s \cdot \log_2(M) }{ \frac{N+1}{T} } = \frac{N \cdot \frac{1}{T_s} \cdot \log_2(M)} { \frac{N+1}{NT_s} } = \log_2(M) \cdot \frac{N^2}{N+1} 
$$
But I can't find any authority that confirms this, and when I ask ChatGPT and Claude 3.5 they first both say: No $\eta^{OFDM} = \log_2(M) \cdot \frac{N}{N+1} $ and when I show them the calculation they say it's what I wrote is correct?
This is assuming no cyclic prefix and rectangular subcarrier pulses.

the way you write it, $R_S$ is a subcarrier symbol rate, not a bit rate.

and you can 100% percent forget all that ChatGPT says about comms engineering. So far, none of the people that posted questions here that cited ChatGPT had a correct statement. So, you're really better off not asking ChatGPT, or you will simply get facts wrong

What is your $B_T$, in words?

other than that, your calculation simply gets an $N$ out of blue sky when you convert $T$ to $T_S$, that is just wrong. And your $+1$ is also not correct: you have $N$ channels of $1/N$ width.

The DFT in OFDM is literally just a base transform;  you don't gain or lose any efficiency.
If you could make an OFDM system work without a guard interval (which usually gets used for a cyclic prefix): the spectral efficiency is exactly that of a single-carrier system of the same bandwidth; in other words, $\eta^{\text{OFDM}} = \log_2 (M)$, regardless of the number of carriers.
You simply split your bandwidth into $N$ independent channels, each transmitting at $1/N$ the rate of the original rate. $N\cdot \frac1N = 1$, regardless which $N$ you choose.
